# How do hackers find the ip address of router or networks they want to hack?

Tags: ip, information-gathering

I've heard news of hackers in different countries being able to infiltrate networks in other countries. What I'm wondering is how these hackers find the ip addresses (without the use of phishing) of the routers, networks, or devices they want to hack. (Note: I am in no way a hacker and I want to know this for purely educational purposes. Even if I did want to hack something, I am in no way smart enough to do so.)

Comment: You can do that for example using Google dorks or Shodan

Comment: Google dorking, social engineering, spoofing, phishing, etc. these are all ways that hackers find information about another and collect all of it to find other information like IP addresses.

Comment: don't forget they often just go looking for *anything* to hack and it turns out to be an important thing in another country just by chance